# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'code' in 'field list'

Tags: python, mysql

I have checked other codes and solutions but I just cant come to find the solution.

[CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3oHT.png)

```
table = "create table salesperson (code int, name varchar(35), salary int, itcode varchar(4))"
cursor.execute(table)

code = int(input('Enter the code:'))
name = input('Enter the name:')
salary = int(input('Enter the salary:'))
itcode = input('Enter the itcode:')

command = "insert into account(code,name,salary,itcode) values(%s,%s,%s,%s)"
values = (code, name, salary, itcode)
cursor.execute(command, values)
mycon.commit()
print('record(s) inserted')
```

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc0mt.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. 
Please provide a complete code example with imports if possible, or tell us what libraries you are using.
How are you interacting with MySQL other than through Python? Have you got phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench installed to verify that the table is being created?

Comment: I notice that you created table `salesperson` with the column `code`, but then you are inserting into a different table `account`, and you have not shown what columns are part of that table. So it's possible that `code` is not in the table `account`, yes?

Comment: @BillKarwin, good spot! I missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you separate the creation of table entities into its own function. Then use MySQL Workbench or another tool to verify that your schema is being created correctly.

Looks like you are creating one table `salesperson` but inserting into `account`? Check that out.

Comment: create table is a statement that does an [implicit commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html) in MySQL.

Comment: Just learnt something, thanks - will modify this answer

Comment: thanks !!!
i wasted hours on it I couldnt find it

God am stupid

Comment: It's all a part of the journey :) good luck!